# To find the missing digits in pythonic way

Tags: python-3.x

I have two strings some_str and actual_str. I want to find out the missing digits of some_str that are found in actual_str.

```
some_str = 'WATER9'
actual_str = '3123459'

pos = some_str.find('WATER')

len_actual_str = len(actual_str)

len_some_str_no_water = len(some_str.replace('WATER',''))

print(some_str)
print(actual_str)

print('Missing Digits: ',actual_str[pos: pos + len_actual_str - len_some_str_no_water])
```

inputs:
Case 1:
some_str = '123WATER9'
actual_str = '123456459'

expected output: 45645

Case 2:
some_str = 'WATER'
actual_str = '123456459'

expected output: 123456459

Case 3:
some_str = 'WATER9'
actual_str = '123456459'

expected output: 12345645

Case 4:
some_str = 'WATER459'
actual_str = '123456459'

expected output: 123456

Case 5:
some_str = '12WATER'
actual_str = '123456459'

expected output: 3456459

Note:
If the digits are present else where in the actual_str then it should not be considered. I mean some_str always contains some digits either in the start or in the end. And they sould match in the same position in the actual_str.

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What output would you expect if `some_str` contains digits elsewhere than in last position? Please always include some test data and the expected output for such questions. Also, try to describe clearly the rules that you have to apply to obtain this output: that will help you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop that loops around every character in actual_str and checks for each character in actual_Str if that character is in some_str.

**For example**

```
some_str = 'WATER9'
actual_str = '3123459'

final_str = ''

for char in actual_str:
    if char not in some_str and char.isdigit():
        final_str += char
```

The final_str should contain all the numbers in actual_str that are not in some_str.

Hope That helped!

Comment: Yes, it is pythonic. I also think looping through each character would probably add to the cost.